# Custom iterator isnt printing linked list results

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator, listiterator

Salutations

Currently creating a program where I am using a custom iterator from "Java.util.*". Problem is is that when I am trying to iterate the program nothing is coming out. Here's the code

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ListIterator;

  public class LL_p2{

  public static void main(String[] args){


     LinkedListIterator_1 op = new LinkedListIterator_1();

     op.add(0,"h");
     op.add(1,"2");
     op.add(2,"4");




     Iterator<String> s = op.iterator();
     while(s.hasNext()){
         System.out.println(s.next() + " ");

     }

     //System.out.println(o);
}
```

}

```
   class LinkedListIterator_1<E>
    implements java.util.Iterator<E> {
  Node<E> head, tail;
  Node<E> current = head; // Current index
  int size = 0;
  public LinkedListIterator_1() {
  }

  public LinkedListIterator_1(int index) {
    // Implement this for Exercise 24.3
  }

  public void add(int index,E e) {
      if (index == 0) {
            addFirst(e);

          }
          else if (index >= size) {
            addLast(e);
            index++;
          }
          else {
            Node<E> current = tail;

            for (int i = 1; i < index; i++) {
              current = current.next;
           }

            Node<E> temp = current.next;
            current.next = new Node<>(e);
            (current.next).previous = current;
            (current.next).next = temp;
            size++;
          }
  }

      public void addFirst(E e) {
          Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(e); // Create a new node

          // This is orginal source code
           newNode.next = head; // link the new node with the head
           newNode.previous = null;
           head = newNode; // head points to the new node

          size++; // Increase list size

          if (tail == null) // the new node is the only node in list
            tail = head;
        }

        public void addLast(E e) {
              Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(e); // Create a new for element e

              if (tail == null) {
                head = tail = newNode; // The new node is the only node in list
              }
              else {
                tail.next = newNode; // Link the new with the last node
                newNode.previous = tail;
                tail = tail.next; // tail now points to the last node
              }

              size++; // Increase size
            }



  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
    return (current != null);
  }

  @Override
  public E next() {
    E e = current.element;
    current = current.next;
    return e;
  }

  @Override
  public void remove() {
    // Left as an exercise
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("[");

      Node<E> current = head;
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        result.append(current.element);
        current = current.next;
        if (current != null) {
          result.append(", "); // Separate two elements with a comma
        }
        else {
          result.append("]"); // Insert the closing ] in the string
        }
      }
      return result.toString();
  }
        public java.util.Iterator<E> iterator() {
              return new LinkedListIterator_1();
            }

            public java.util.Iterator<E> iterator(int index) {
              return new LinkedListIterator_1(index);
            }

}


class Node<E> {


  E element;
  Node<E> next;
  Node<E> previous; 
  public Node(E element) {
    this.element = element;
  }
}
```

Every time I run this, after I add every element, nothing is printed via the iterable statement. I am confused whether its something with the add statement or the custom iterator statement I created.

Also every time I implement the LinkedListIterator_1 class, it will not run unless a  is there. I am conivnced this is the problem, but I have no other way of making the program work. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Please give us an overview of your code and architecture instead of just throwing a huge amount of code at us. Will be far more easy for us to provide help more quickly.

Comment: My mistake, still pretty new to programming in general and effectively usage Stackoverflow.

Comment: Yeah, no problem at all. Just picture yourself in our position and ask yourself what could be helpful. You'll quickly get the hang of it :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `current` points to `null`.

The fix: change the `iterator()` method to:

```
public java.util.Iterator<E> iterator() {
    current = head;
    return this;
}
```

After applying the fix when I run the code I get the output:

```
h 
2 
4
```

Full code:

```
class LinkedListIterator_1<E>
    implements java.util.Iterator<E> {
    Node<E> head, tail;
    Node<E> current; // Current index
    int size = 0;
    public LinkedListIterator_1() {
    }

    public LinkedListIterator_1(int index) {
        current = head;
        while (index > 0) {
            current = current.next;
            index--;
        }
    }

    public void add(int index,E e) {
        if (index == 0) {
            addFirst(e);

        }
        else if (index >= size) {
            addLast(e);
            index++;
        }
        else {
            Node<E> current = tail;

            for (int i = 1; i < index; i++) {
                current = current.next;
            }

            Node<E> temp = current.next;
            current.next = new Node<>(e);
            (current.next).previous = current;
            (current.next).next = temp;
            size++;
        }
    }

    public void addFirst(E e) {
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(e); // Create a new node

        // This is orginal source code
        newNode.next = head; // link the new node with the head
        newNode.previous = null;
        head = newNode; // head points to the new node

        size++; // Increase list size

        if (tail == null) // the new node is the only node in list
            tail = head;
    }

    public void addLast(E e) {
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(e); // Create a new for element e

        if (tail == null) {
            head = tail = newNode; // The new node is the only node in list
        }
        else {
            tail.next = newNode; // Link the new with the last node
            newNode.previous = tail;
            tail = tail.next; // tail now points to the last node
        }

        size++; // Increase size
    }



    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (current != null);
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
        E e = current.element;
        current = current.next;
        return e;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        // Left as an exercise
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("[");

        Node<E> current = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            result.append(current.element);
            current = current.next;
            if (current != null) {
                result.append(", "); // Separate two elements with a comma
            }
            else {
                result.append("]"); // Insert the closing ] in the string
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
    public java.util.Iterator<E> iterator() {
        current = head;
        return this;
    }

    public java.util.Iterator<E> iterator(int index) {
        return new LinkedListIterator_1(index);
    }

}
```